# Error during install of Memgraph Lab on Lima

Tags: memgraphdb

I am trying to install Memgraph Lab and after downloading it for linux debian I get the following error - "`dpkg:error processing archive MemgraphLab-2.7.1-amd64.deb (--install): package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)`". I am working on Lima (VM for Mac). Does anybody maybe know what could be the issue and if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re installing Memgraph Lab to connect to a running Memgraph instance in Lima, you can try installing Memgraph Lab on your Mac ([download for Mac](https://memgraph.com/download#memgraph-lab)) and connect to a running Memgraph instance that you started in Lima.

If you have Mac M1, you can download Lab prepared for M1 chip (arm64).

On old Macs, only "Mac OS" version will work. On new Macs (M1 chip), both "Mac OS" and "Mac OS (M1 chip)" will work, but the one for M1 chip will be faster.